# intersection between derived and frattini subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Can you help me in finding a group with  the non-trivial derived subgroup and the non-trivial Frattini subgroup such that intersection of them is trivial?

Comment: Tank you for your attention to my question. I can not construct  a group with this property to obtain my desirable condition. for example, the direct product of  the dihedral group of order 18 and the cyclic group of order prime has the property.

Comment: Try taking a direct product of two groups G,H, where G has trivial Frattini and nontrivial derived subgroups, and $H$ has trivial derived and nontrivial Frattini subgroups.

Comment: Sorry I think my hint was unclear - I have rewritten it.

Comment: Tank you very much for your answer.

Comment: sorry. i can not constrict such group with  my desirable condition.

Comment: Well I explained exactly how to do it. There is an example with $|G|=6$ and $|H|=4$.

Comment: sorry. Tank you very  much for your  guidance and patience.